# How to check if a command user has a certain role

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been trying to make a quick bot for a friend, however I have come across something I cant fix. Whenever I try to access the member from the message it returns null. I am trying to find the users roles so I can check if they have a certain one.

The root of this problem that member is null inside the message. Therefor I cannot read from  a null value.

`client.on('message', message => {`

This is how I am declaring message, and here is a console log of message. https://pastebin.com/vrdg9Wvu

So please can someone help me find a way to compare the command users roles.

Comment: Make sure that you are not inside a dm channel when running the command

Answer (score 0):

Which version of dicord.js are you using?
I don't know where this may come from, maybe if the user who sent the message has left the guild while sending, otherwise I don't know what's wrong. If it's still not working, consider using `message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).then(user => {})`, that may work.

Comment: How do you check what version of discord js youre using?

Comment: That's in your package.json file, you can also type `npm ls` and it'll show you all packages used for this project and their versions.

Comment: discord.js@11.5.1

Comment: Maybe updating your discord.js may change something, there's a lot of changes between discord.js v11 and discord.js v12, and the last version is 12.4.1, but you'll have to change some lines in your code.
See https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html